How can I enter 0x0a in Vim Control-V mode?
Based on this answer, I was able to type Control-V x0b to enter the byte 0b and Control-V x0c to enter the byte 0c.
Many other sequences work as expected.
However, Control-v x0a gives me the byte 0 instead of the expected byte 0a.
Additionally, typing Control-v 10 also gives me the byte 0.
Is there some setting that controls why trying to input 0x0a gives the NUL byte instead of the intended byte?

Apparently this limitation is documented behavior in :help i_CTRL-V_digit:
If you enter a value of 10, it will end up in the file as a 0.  The 10
is a <NL>, which is used internally to represent the <Nul> character. 
When writing the buffer to a file, the <NL> character is translated
into <Nul>.  The <NL> character is written at the end of each line. 
Thus if you want to insert a <NL> character in a file you will have to
make a line break.


Probably a side effect of the choice for "null terminated strings" in C ? ... Vim can't handle "Nul" gracefully because of it, and resorts to using another character to represent Nul ?

@OlivierDulac if you have a question, you should ask it.

Olivier's comment reads to me as if they weren't sure about their hypothesis so I consider the questions marks as a gentle reminder to that.
